# linux dialog --checklist error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am working on following linux dialog box. I am not able to understand it's behavior. This works correctly i.e. correctly displays three checkboxes.

```
#!/bin/sh

dialog --backtitle "Test" \
--title "Checkbox test " \
--checklist "Choose from following"  0 0 0 \
apple "The apple is green" on \
mango "The mango is golden" on \
pappaya "The pappaya is brown" on \
2> /tmp/optional.out
OPTIONAL=`cat /tmp/optional.out | \
    sed -e "s/\"//g" -e "s/ /|/g" -e "s/|$//"`
    echo 'optional :'$OPTIONAL
```

After execution i get following output as.
`optional :apple|mango|pappaya`

However I want to show the user only two options. So I made the following changes.

```
#!/bin/sh

dialog --backtitle "Test" \
--title "Checkbox test " \
--checklist "Choose from following"  0 0 0 \
apple "The apple is green" on \
mango "The mango is golden" on \
#pappaya "The pappaya is brown" on \
2> /tmp/optional.out
OPTIONAL=`cat /tmp/optional.out | \
    sed -e "s/\"//g" -e "s/ /|/g" -e "s/|$//"`
    echo 'optional :'$OPTIONAL
```

But after doing this I get no output i.e. `optional :`. Why is that? How can I make it work.

Comment: Maybe one too many zeros...

Comment: @ l'L'l   Checked that. Put only two zeroes and checked. Didn't work.

Comment: @I'L'I tried that too. didn't work.

Comment: "didn't work"... that's incredibly useful information; "maybe try something else"...

Comment: @I'L'I I am sorry. By didn't work I meant I am still getting `optional:` output. Also, /tmp/optional.out is still empty.

Comment: btw, is `/tmp/optional.out` the same as `/var/tmp/optional.out` on your system?

Comment: oh yes! my editing mistake. They are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now thinking you did **comment and broke your line**. (it happens many times to me)

You may try this:

```
#!/bin/sh

dialog --backtitle "Test" \
--title "Checkbox test " \
--checklist "Choose from following"  0 0 0 \
apple "The apple is green" on \
mango "The mango is golden" on \
2> /var/tmp/optional.out
OPTIONAL=`cat /var/tmp/optional.out | \
    sed -e "s/\"//g" -e "s/ /|/g" -e "s/|$//"`
    echo 'optional :'$OPTIONAL
```